# Wireless Driver for HCL ME (Realtek rtl8191sevb)?

Tags: wireless, drivers, realtek

I recently bought HCL ME with Windows.

I formatted and installed Ubuntu netbook version. I am getting wifi is not connection it looks disabled in network place.

My network controller is `Realtek semiconductor co., ltd rtl8191sevb rev 10`

I am unable to get this driver to install can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a Ubuntu forum post here [wireless disconnects periodically (RTL8191SEvB Wireless LAN Controller (rev 10))](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1644053) which deals with your problem however I would try this first

```
rmmod r8192se_pci
```

then

```
modprobe r8192se_pci hwwep=0
```

if this doesn't work then reboot and everything will be back to normal if it works then you can add it as a permanent fix to `/etc/modprobe.d/realtek.conf`

and add this line

```
options r8192se_pci hwwep=0
```

Hope this helps

Comment: No problem found the fix on the Frozentux site by Oskar Andreasson here is a link to the blog post I would make a bookmark or save the details on U1 as you may have to do the same thing on 11.04 if you upgrade. I have a few things I always have to do after an Upgrade.http://www.frozentux.net/2010/12/ubuntu-10-10-r8192se_pci-driver-on-the-toshiba-satellite-t130-17e-realtek-rtl8191sevb/

Answer (score 0):

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1600498 (post by rtomakov)

This thread helped me to get it working in by HCL ME.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.