# WiFi works perfectly on Windows, but drops on Ubuntu

Tags: networking, wireless, drivers, realtek

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Wireless Driver for HCL ME (Realtek rtl8191sevb)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23085/wireless-driver-for-hcl-me-realtek-rtl8191sevb)

I have a dual-boot computer with Windows XP on one partition and Ubuntu 10.10 on the other.  In Windows XP I can connect to a hidden wireless network (WPA-PSK AES) perfectly, and I was finally able to install the driver for the adapter on Ubuntu (RNX-N180UBE, hardware id RTL8191SU).

It works fine when I first boot the computer and log in, but then after a few minutes the network suddenly stops working completely.  If I try to reconnect it, the network manager claims to have connected, but in actuality it's still down.

At some points, I have been able to connect to a public network even while the private network didn't work, but that eventually wouldn't work at all either.

Comment: this is not a duplicate of that, rtl8192se is a pci card and the kernel modules work fine, whereas rtl8192cu is a usb card and you need the proprietary driver

Comment: http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PFid=48&Level=5&Conn=4&ProdID=229&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false&Downloads=true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was fixed in this forum thread:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=10428524#post10428524

It turns out all I had to do was install the wicd network manager.  But thank you for your responses.

Comment: you may want to check out the proprietary driver http://askubuntu.com/a/395826/167115