# Compile and install rtl8192cu driver

Tags: wireless, drivers, realtek

Can someone help me with this problem ? I am new to Linux, so I do not know commands and I never did something like installing or compiling with command-line.

I bought WiFi adapter from Edimax, model EW-7811UN for my PC (not laptop, so I do not have wifi card, only ethernet). When I go through guide on CD, I came across a version of kernel. It said I need version 2.6, but I have 3.5.0-22-generic.

I got errors like I do not have file or folder etc. Can someone tell me where I can download compiled driver and where I need to put it? Or some other advice. I don't want downgrade kernel when it is not necessary.

Comment: It does not seem to work anymore; 13.04, 3.8.0-25-generic; the kernel driver allows connection to open wifis, but the connection is severed after 2 minutes or so; then I tried to build the Realtek driver with all patches I could find; it compiles but the connection is as flaky as before; furthermore when I unplugged the adapter, I got a kernel panic, any helps?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala a little late but try one of the git hub versions with the newer kernels and enable the module with 8192cu instead of rtl8192cu or build with the driver from the realtek website using kernel 3.2LTS

Comment: NP now for me now, I do not even know where this device is anymore, I just needed it for my laptop after the internal antenna was severed (now fixed)

Answer (score 18):

If you run into this problem, what worked for me was installing the following driver:
https://github.com/pvaret/rtl8192cu-fixes

From the [README.md](https://github.com/pvaret/rtl8192cu-fixes/blob/master/README.md) file:

> ### Installation
>
> Ensure you have the necessary prerequisites:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential dkms
> ```
>
> Clone this repository:
>
> ```
> git clone https://github.com/pvaret/rtl8192cu-fixes.git
> ```
>
> Set it up as a DKMS module:
>
> ```
> sudo dkms add ./rtl8192cu-fixes
> ```
>
> Build and install it (this version number may change, it is .11 as of November 07 2019)
>
> ```
> sudo dkms install 8192cu/1.11
> ```
>
> Refresh the module list:
>
> ```
> sudo depmod -a
> ```
>
> Ensure the native (and broken) kernel driver is blacklisted:
>
> ```
> sudo cp ./rtl8192cu-fixes/blacklist-native-rtl8192.conf /etc/modprobe.d/
> ```
>
> And reboot. You're done.

Comment: As a note I just did this and after the line: `sudo dkms install 8192cu/1.8` I got an error. That error was: `Error! Could not find module source directory.
Directory: /usr/src/8192cu-1.8 does not exist.` Turns out that I needed to change the `/usr/src/8192cu-1.8` to `/usr/src/8192cu-1.9` Must have been a recent update to the GIT and these instructions are out of date by that one digit.

Comment: Take a look in the /usr/src directory.  You may have 1.9 instead if you downloaded the latest version. ;)

Comment: This works fine for me for TL-WN823N V1.2 under Ubuntu 16.04, Thank you very much!

Comment: This works on Ubuntu 16.10.  However, a question: `lsmod` shows me that the new driver is working instead of the old one (and my connection is now stable...). However, if I click on "connection information" _visually_ on my unity tray, it says that `rtl8192cu` (instead of just `8192cu`) is still in use. Does someone know why that is the case?

Answer (score 13):

**12.04 & 14.04+: you can view [these](http://bernaerts.dyndns.org/linux/74-ubuntu/277-ubuntu-precise-dwa-131-rev-b1) instructions or just do as I say.**

(use these instructions when your wireless USB device [rtl8192cu] is not automatically recognized by Ubuntu)

```
sudo modprobe rtl8192cu
echo "2001 330D" | sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/drivers/rtl8192cu/new_id
echo "rtl8192cu" | sudo tee -a /etc/modules
```

Then, edit /etc/rc.local by opening the file with your favorite text editor like in this example:

```
sudo gedit /etc/rc.local
```

make sure it says . . .

```
echo "2001 330D" | tee /sys/bus/usb/drivers/rtl8192cu/new_id

exit 0
```

You can use the wireless now or, alternatively, you can make sure you have all of your work saved before you type:

```
sudo reboot
```

Your wireless driver should start up automatically.

---

**To compile and install the proprietary Realtek 8192cu driver, run the following commands in an open terminal:**

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install git build-essential linux-headers-generic dkms
git clone https://github.com/dz0ny/rt8192cu.git --depth 1
cd rt8192cu
sudo make dkms
```

For hard installation use:

```
make
sudo make install
```

instead of `sudo make dkms` .

To enable this driver, use the command:

```
sudo modprobe 8192cu
```

Finally, update /etc/modules with this command before you reboot:

```
echo '8192cu' | sudo tee -a /etc/modules
```

---

[Souce #1: bernaerts.dyndns.org](http://bernaerts.dyndns.org/linux/74-ubuntu/277-ubuntu-precise-dwa-131-rev-b1)

[Source #2: github.com/dz0ny](https://github.com/dz0ny/rt8192cu)

Comment: This works awesome for D-link A-131

Comment: Thank you so much. I fought with my Asus USBN13 for two days before finding your answer. It worked when everything else had failed and I was about to give up.

Comment: Great, has worked for TP-Link TL-WN821N on Xubuntu 12.04 on the first pass.

Comment: I can't build the driver source:
`$ sudo make install`

`install -p -m 644 8192cu.ko  /lib/modules/3.13.0-44-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/`

`install: cannot stat ‘8192cu.ko’: No such file or directory`

Comment: @Andy First, run `make`. Then, run `sudo make install`. I edited the answer. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Proposed adding to this post regarding the top fix: Reviewers please discard that! After much work with each of the methods, none works for me.  Flash-heavy sites take out the connection every time. Sadly, this device is not usable because the mfr won't provide an updated driver.

Answer (score 4):

Generally speaking, any Linux driver on a vendor CD would be outdated, and, in most cases, would not be worth bothering with. The RTL8192cu module has been part of the Linux kernel since version 2.6.38, so that, ideally, you'd only need to plug the device in, and it would work. Unfortunately, that particular module hasn't ever worked, and, IMHO, a fix has been long overdue ([bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/852190)).

So, what should you do? Plug in the device. Verify that the network manager 'sees' the wireless networks around (may also verify that the correct module is loaded by running `lsmod | grep 8192`). Try connecting to your network. If that doesn't work, try connecting to any network. If that doesn't work, you are affected by the bug, and will have to try the driver from http://www.realtek.com.

- Download the driver from [here](http://www.realtek.com/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=48&PFid=48&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false&Downloads=true#2772), and put the downloaded file into your home folder.
- Blacklist the existing module. In a terminal window, run

  `gksu gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`, add `blacklist rtl8192cu` to the bottom, 
  save and exit, then reboot.
- Extract the downloaded archive: right click, Extract here, or run

  `unzip RTL8192xC_USB_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105.zip`
- Install. In a terminal window, run

  `sudo bash ./RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/install.sh`

Comment: Thanks very much, it's better, but I got problem... Compilation is ok, but after it I need edit install.sh or something because new folder with compiled driver is "locked" and I have to do chmod 777 on every folder and file for root ... by tutorial without editing my PC freezed and I had to reboot (after line compiling driver ok and before line with remove, insert and install driver). Do you have any ideas or can you help me with fast editing rights ? Or some simple tut. how to do it through terminal and not by install.sh :) Thanks

Comment: You should not `chmod` anything, and I would not recommend playing with permission. Simply do what's posted above, nothing else. :~)

Comment: Hm.. but my PC freezed ... I have to reboot.. I can't do anything and when I reboot, I see created folder by installer with lock icon :/ PC freeze before step with remove, insert and install .. It show me line that authorization is required, but it freezes and I have to reboot :( I can't go through that...

Comment: Not sure. Running `install.sh` with `sudo` should give you correct permissions.

Comment: maybe I didn't have rights because of freezing PC... but I don't know why it freezed :/ Is it possible to do this manually ? without autoinstall ... maybe I'll find some problems during process or something like that..

Comment: So..I do it with this tutorial: http://www.r-statistics.com/2011/11/edimax-ew-7811un-usb-wireless-connecting-to-a-network-on-ubuntu-11-10/   everything went ok, but now I can't connect to my network. Password is right and I can see other networks. But connection manager says that Wireless connection is disconnected :/ also I can't see menu Wireless network (I can't click on it) and menu Wireless networks I can't click too :/ So.. I click on name of my network and type password, then PC can't connect and show me Wireless connection disconnected.. Do you know, or someone else, why it is so ?

Comment: Oh, I forgot mantion that I have Ubuntu 64bit 12.10

Comment: Appologies, but I don't want to comment on someone else's tutorial. Your PC does not freeze any more, so there is progress. Hope you'll find a solution eventually.

Comment: I see, but I want to know, why is menu unclickable and what about 64bit (I have only USB wifi adapter, and ethernet on motherboard, nothing else.., Is it problem to see menu ?)

Comment: The lock icon means the network is password protected. Try `sudo modprobe 8192cu` before you try connecting again, that is IF the realtek driver installed. I always run into errors with the install.sh script so I just extracted the driver and used `cd` to change directories into the driver folder and then `sudo make` , `sudo make install`, and finally `sudo modprobe 8192cu` to get it working.

Answer (score 2):

It works well. Only issue you should cd to the directory first.

eg.

```
cd RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105

sudo bash ./install.sh
```

Comment: The only trouble I had installing with this method was that one of the compressed archives called by install.sh had an extra directory when uncompressed so the install script couldn't find it. To fix this problem you can edit the install script or uncompress the archive, copy and paste the directory found in the top level into where the compressed directory is, delete the compressed directory and compress the pasted directory using the proper name. Then, run `sudo ./install.sh` and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Can you provide details of what commands you used to setup the drivers or be specific about the errors when you tried ? I also found : [installing Edimax EW7811](http://kisdigital.wordpress.com/2010/12/28/setup-edimax-usb-wireless-adaptor-in-ubuntu/), to install the drivers sequentially if the manual wasn't clear enough also try using the search bar too, many have reported errors on Edimax drivers as well.

Link to the linux drivers for Edimax EW7811UN from their website : [Download](http://www.edimax.com/en/downloadBox.php?pd_id=347&download_link=../images/Image/Driver_Utility/Wireless/NIC/EW-7811Un/rtl8192CU_8188CU_linux_v2.0.939.20100726.zip) (in case if you have any other version installer)

Comment: I use some tutorials, but I freezed with command sudo make ... <p>
cp: nie je možné stat() `/autoconf_rtl8192c_usb_linux.h': 
</p>
This is what terminal said. It is in slovak, because I have slovak version of Ubuntu 12.10 :) I think you can translate it easily..

Comment: EDIT: errors are here: http://kario.wz.cz/upload/linux.txt   I have slovak version of Ubuntu 12.10 so errors are in slovak too :))

Comment: Try `make clean` before your first command, that solves the problem some time.

Comment: I always do make clean before make like in tutorial, clean run without error but make do errors, but I don't know how to "repair" them ..

Comment: @MarošKáčko-DonnieKario the reason it does not work is because, starting with kernel 3.4 there were some changes to the kernel headers and some of the macros used to make the driver that are now depreciated and so the build results in the errors you receive. You can build with the standard LTS kernel 3.2 or you can use the updated DKMS version from github as described in my answer.

Answer (score -2):

I downloaded a newer version of the driver and installed it with:
sudo dkms install 8192cu/1.9

So, keep in mind to install using your driver version.