# Wireless connects to network but no internet - Edimax EW-7612 PIn

Tags: wireless, networking, 13.10

I have an Edimax EW-7612PIn wireless card. Booted up my computer (13.10) with it inserted, and I was able to connect to my Wifi without issue.

However, I am unable to access internet sites.

Does anyone know what might be the issue?

Edited with console commands:
lspci -nn | grep 0280:

```
:~$ lspci -nn | grep 0280
06:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8191SEvB Wireless LAN Controller [10ec:8172] (rev 10)
```

and nm-tool:

```
NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

- Device: eth0 -----------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            sky2
  State:             unavailable
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        20:CF:30:E2:90:89

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes
    Speed:           1000 Mb/s

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         off


- Device: wlan0  [HITRON-DC50] -------------------------------------------------
  Type:              802.11 WiFi
  Driver:            rtl8192se
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        00:1F:1F:FA:70:26

  Capabilities:
    Speed:           150 Mb/s

  Wireless Properties
    WEP Encryption:  yes
    WPA Encryption:  yes
    WPA2 Encryption: yes

  Wireless Access Points (* = current AP)
*HITRON-DC50:    Infra, 78:8D:F7:BE:DC:58, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 60 WPA WPA2

  IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         192.168.0.13
    Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
    Gateway:         192.168.0.1

    DNS:             192.168.0.1
```

Ping results:

```
PING 192.168.0.1 (192.168.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- 192.168.0.1 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 2014ms
```

and

```
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
3 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time
```

[iwconfig](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6885272/)

[This is a potentially relevant question but I have a different rtl.... so I am reluctant to go ahead on that](https://askubuntu.com/questions/246236/compile-and-install-rtl8192cu-driver)

Comment: Please edit your question to add the results of these two terminal commands: lspci -nn | grep 0280 and also: nm-tool

Comment: @chili555 thanks for taking the time. I have made the edits that you suggested.

Comment: Can you ping? ping -c3 192.168.0.1 and also: ping -c3 8.8.8.8

Comment: @chili555 ping results added

Comment: Now I'm sorry I asked!

Answer (score 0):

It is quite strange that you can ping the outside world; i.e. Google's DNS nameserver 8.8.8.8, but not your own router! Have you placed any settings in the Network Manager boxes? Generally, NM will handle all details for us without any intervention. Just be certain NM is set to Infrastructure and to use DHCP. Ordinarily any and all other settings should be left blank.

Is your wireless mode Managed; that is, configured for the most part by negotiation with the router?

```
iwconfig
```

What do these tell us?

```
route -n
traceroute 8.8.8.8
```

As these are likely to be lengthy, please copy and paste the results here and give us the link in your reply. http://paste.ubuntu.com/

Please try a driver parameter:

```
sudo modprobe -r rtl8192se
sudo modprobe rtl8192se swenc=1
```

If this helps, we can write a file to make it persistent.

What do the message logs have to report?

```
dmesg | grep -e rtl -e wlan
```

As it may be lengthy, use http://paste.ubuntu.com/ please.

Comment: ok it seems I am now getting 100% loss on 8.8.8.8, I must have not run the command while on wireless, I am sorry. But at least now that makes sense. Requested pastebin: http://paste.ubuntu.com/6885272/

Comment: How about the traceroute?

Comment: traceroute results in nothing apart from: 1  * * * 2  * * *

Comment: no success with the modprobe commands unfortunately