# Wi-fi speed dramatically low on Ubuntu vs Windows

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, internet

I have just installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my machine. My kernel version is:

```
3.16.0-34-generic
```

My problem is that download speed in Ubuntu (measured via `speedtest.net`) is `0.78 Mbps` while on Windows (installed on the same machine) I have `21,84 Mbps`. What can be important is that I also had a problem with constantly disconnecting Wi-Fi, which I resolved by forcing `AES` encryption in my Wi-Fi router. My Wi-Fi adapter is

```
D-Link DWA-121 Wireless N 150 Pico USB Adapter
```

and the relevant part of output of `iwconfig` is:

```
wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"UPC1307036"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: 64:7C:34:3D:ED:CE   
          Bit Rate=72.2 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=62/70  Signal level=-48 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:134   Missed beacon:0
```

I tried the solutions from other questions of this kind, but they didn't work, so I'm starting a new question.

Comment: I hope my question is worded properly. Please let me know if it lacks some important informations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compile and install the proprietary Realtek 8192cu driver. To do this, run the following commands in an open terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install git build-essential linux-headers-generic dkms
git clone https://github.com/dz0ny/rt8192cu.git --depth 1
cd rt8192cu
sudo make dkms
```

For hard installation use:

```
make
sudo make install
```

instead of `sudo make dkms` .

To enable this driver, use the command:

```
sudo modprobe 8192cu
```

Finally, update /etc/modules with this command before you reboot:

```
echo '8192cu' | sudo tee -a /etc/modules
```

---

[Source: github.com/dz0ny](https://github.com/dz0ny/rt8192cu)

Also: https://askubuntu.com/a/395826/167115

Comment: Unfortunately, no luck. `sudo modprobe 8192cu` command gives the error: `modprobe: ERROR: could not insert '8192cu': Device or resource busy`.

Comment: Ok, it's because I had probably trail of attemption of solving this (or previous) issue in my `/etc/modules`. After I cleaned this file and rebooted the system, everything works properly. So thank you very much for your time and I finally have the opportunity to accept the answer after long presence on StackExchange. :)

Comment: Also, hard installation is not recommended and the DKMS method is preferred as the DKMS method will automatically install with a new kernel update whereas a hard install will require the driver be reinstalled each time a new kernel is installed.