# Missing kernel headers for Odroid U2

Tags: drivers, apt, kernel, arm, dkms

I have an ODroid U2 running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and **Linux version 3.8.13.30**.

I am trying to get my USB WiFi dongle working through [this tutorial](https://askubuntu.com/questions/246236/compile-and-install-rtl8192cu-driver).

However, at the `sudo dkms install 8192cu/1.10` stage, I am getting the following error:

```
Error! Your kernel headers for kernel 3.8.13.30 cannot be found.
Please install the linux-headers-3.8.13.30 package, or use the --kernelsource dir option to tell DKMS where it's located`
```

So, I did `dpkg -l | grep linux-headers` to find that `linux-headers-3.13.0-51` was installed at `/usr/src`.

I passed this data to DKMS through the `--kernelsourcedir` option but got the same error:

I also did `apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname-r)` but got an `Unable to locate package` error.

What am I doing wrong/How can I fix this?

Comment: Wonder what you did to use a kernel from a previous release, as ubuntu 14.04 comes with Linux 3.13.

Comment: @xangua I didn't check exactly. I recently did a fresh install of Ubuntu and got an option to update kernel. When I did, this is what I have currently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the correct headers [here](http://forum.odroid.com/viewtopic.php?f=52&t=5908).

How to add this repository:

```
sudo -i
cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d
wget https://oph.mdrjr.net/meveric/sources.lists/meveric-all-main.list
wget -O- http://oph.mdrjr.net/meveric/meveric.asc | apt-key add -
exit
sudo apt-get update
```

You can then use APT to install the headers you need.

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at this page: http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/, you'll see that particular version is not available (anymore). It is probably better to install a newer kernel from the page mentioned and then try to compile the dkms module again.

Comment: I just updated my kernel via the ODroid Utility.

Comment: No matter how you update if you don't install matching headers you can't compile kernel modules, like the error message tells you also.

Comment: So, how would I update the kernel to match the already installed linux-headers?

Comment: You can't. You'll have to match the headers with the kernel installed not the other way around. Matching the kernel with the headers means effectively downgrading your kernel which is not advisable or even impossible. Install a newer kernel with the marching headers using dpkg.

Comment: So that is what I tried. However, as you pointed out, the headers for that particular version isn't available anymore.

Comment: Install a newer kernel with the marching headers using dpkg. Mind the correct architecture because odroid is neither 386 nor amd64.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23382/discussion-between-kanishka-ganguly-and-wie5ooma).