# Wireless adaptor (TL-WN8200ND) shows the networks but wont connect

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, tp-link

Hello i just bought my new wireless adaptor and is the ( **TL-WN8200ND** ) and i have ubuntu 17.04 in my computer i have a dual boot pc with windows 7 and ubuntu the problem is in the ubuntu the adaptor shows me all the wifi networks i click to connect it gives me the password i write the password correct im sure for that because i check for caps lock and language, it takes 10-15 secons then is giving me the message you are disconected and i know its not router fault because i have tried with other wireless routers + i open my phone hotspot and again same problem.If anyone knows something how to fix this please tell me i really need ubuntu!

Comment: try this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/395826/694267

Comment: I dont have internet connection in the system is there any option to download things from windows where my adaptor is working and after install it in the ubunut

Comment: drivers need to be compiled to the kernel you are using. you might be able to find a precompiled one (may give the same performance as the generic one), but normally you download the source and compile it (this gives the best results).  it is possible that you could download the sourse from windows

Comment: Sorry but im not so good at ubuntu if u have the time to tell me how to do that ?

Comment: I don't know where to get it from windows

Comment: @ravery It is quite unlikely that the three-year-old driver you linked is better than that included in 17.04.

Comment: @chili555 -- I use it myself, works better than the ditsro driver which continually disconnects. the only difficulty here is it need to add the divice code for the USB

Comment: Please try this first: https://askubuntu.com/questions/902992/ubuntu-gnome-17-04-wi-fi-not-working-mac-address-keeps-changing

Answer (score 1):

Please implement the fix outlined here: [Ubuntu GNOME 17.04: wi-fi not working -- mac address keeps changing?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/902992/ubuntu-gnome-17-04-wi-fi-not-working-mac-address-keeps-changing)

Next, please check to see if two possibly conflicting drivers are loaded:

```
lsmod | grep rtl
```

If you find that *both* rtl8192cu and rtl8xxxu are loaded, then blacklist one:

```
sudo -i
echo "blacklist rtl8192cu"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
exit
```

After making these two changes, reboot and let us hear the result.