# No Wifi Option in dropdown

Tags: 14.04, networking, drivers, network-manager, realtek

I know there have been a few similar questions asked, this is not a duplicate though, those people got personalized help and their situation is not mine. I have ubuntu 14.04 and the wifi has never worked right. I have followed a few posts but nothing has fixed the issue. I recently got some great help from one of my previous questions: [14.04 LTS Wifi sometimes disconnects, wired connection rapidly connects and disconnects](https://askubuntu.com/questions/934806/14-04-lts-wifi-sometimes-disconnects-wired-connection-rapidly-connects-and-disc)

After installing the 3rd party driver and rebooting I have not had a wifi signal in my network manager.

I have a Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter

What should I do? I just tried this post:
[No WiFi option in network manager](https://askubuntu.com/questions/834362/no-wifi-option-in-network-manager)

which led me to this:
[Compile and install rtl8192cu driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/246236/compile-and-install-rtl8192cu-driver)

...where I followed the update outlined in the first answer.

I'm at loss right now, any guidance would be appreciated.

edit:
Thanks pilot6 but his problem is loss of connection, my problem right now is that I cant see my wifi networks to connect to on the desktop. I installed the driver from that post though

ifconfig

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 80:3f:5d:06:23:c3  
          inet addr:192.168.10.73  Bcast:192.168.10.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::823f:5dff:fe06:23c3/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:3122 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1628 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:715906 (715.9 KB)  TX bytes:345684 (345.6 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:624 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:624 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:67561 (67.5 KB)  TX bytes:67561 (67.5 KB)
```

rfkill list:

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

maxbisesi@Slacktop:~$ iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

Comment: if you installed a third party driver without using dkms, you need to turn off secure boot for kernel vers 4.4 or newer

Comment: @ravery With DKMS the same thing.

Comment: @pilot6 -- I thought  DKMS would sign it ...

Comment: No, It doesn't.

Comment: Ok I tried turning off secure boot in my bios menu but it wouldn't boot at all, before I installed that third party driver I could at least kind of connect to wifi but now I cant even see the networks on the desktop.